# Making multiple AJAX calls $.when.apply($, array) not working properly

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to learn more about ajax calls and doing some testing. I am running into a snag due to async.. With the help of [this website](https://medium.com/sungthecoder/making-multiple-ajax-calls-and-deciphering-when-apply-array-b35d1b4b1f50) I have found what I believe should work.. Somehow things still arent running properly. I have fiddled a ton, but still have yet to make things work how Id like.

Background:

1. Capturing a variable amount of ids in `array`
2. Iterating through `$.ajax` calls to update ids (api batch request not possible).

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var deffered, deferreds = [];
    $.each(arr, function(i, array) {
      deferred = $.ajax({ ...
        success: function(data) {console.log('complete');},
        error: function(data) {...}
      });
      deferreds.push(deferred);
    });
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(console.log('done'));
  });
});
```

When running code above (also see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37816/rws5mfhn/) for more details) and checking my console.log it shows 'done' occurring before any 'completes' are made (picture below).

Please help me understand what is wrong with code. I want all ajax calls to `console.log('complete')` before the `console.log('done')`. From my understanding that is the point of `$.when.apply`.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/YNGcm/21/ and share link

Comment: @GoodSamaritan I apologize, I was thinking maybe it was a simple oversight that didn't require all detail. I edited original post to include a public fiddle link.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: have to try my answer? is it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the sample working code. Please add promise in each request

```
deferred = $.ajax({ ...
        success: function(data) {console.log('complete');},
        error: function(data) {...}
      }).promise();
```

and change in this line

```
 $.when.apply(this, deferreds)
```

Please run this code and verify it

```js
function doSomething() {
  var arrDef = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var deferred = $.ajax({
        url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('complete');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log('fail');
        }
      }).promise();
      
    arrDef.push(deferred);
  }
  return arrDef;
}

  var getters = doSomething();
  // use apply to call $.when 
  $.when.apply(this, getters).then(function() {
    console.log('Final complete');
    // correctly writes out all responses
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer did help me fix the issue. Thanks!